# Reticulate: missing required dependencies [dateutl] importing pandas

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas, reticulate

I am trying to use [Reticulate library](https://rstudio.github.io/reticulate/index.html). I am trying some examples using `pandas`. These are the instructions I make in the R terminal:

```
library(reticulate)
use_python("/usr/local/bin/python3.7")
virtualenv_create("test-v37")
virtualenv_install("test-v37", "pandas")
import("pandas")
```

Resulting, unfortunately with this error.

```
Error in py_module_import(module, convert = convert) : 
  ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['dateutil']

Detailed traceback: 
  File "/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
```

If I use python3 console there is no problem about dependencies.

Specifications:
I am using `R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"`
in a macOS Mojave 10.14.4

Do know how to fix it?

Comment: are `pandas` and `dateutil` saved in different folders? my guess would be R found `pandas` but not the other package.

Comment: @Mike how do I see the folders in which they are installed ?

Comment: @Parfait, yes it runs smoothly in my virtualenv. It actually works in my linux, but no clue why it doesn't on my mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this Github issue comment: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/478#issuecomment-481808953

it seems that forcing the virtualenv with (from the e.g.):

`use_virtualenv("test-v37", required = TRUE)`

will fix the problem, thanks everyone